# Sitecore 6 WFFM: How to customize reports?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, web-forms-for-marketers

I have a few fields that I don't want to appear in the report. Is there a way to hide them completely (not even show the column header for these fields)?

I tried to create my own ISaveAction with the intent to filter out those fields before they get saved to the DB, but even if they don't appear in the AdaptedResultList that is sent to the DataManager.InsertForm the columns associated to these fields still appear in the reports.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Out of the box functionality, the answer is that if you mean one of the reports in the Form Reports area of WFFM, you most likely can, depending on the report.  If you mean one of the reports that you can see a "Design" button on top when you view it, then you know that it's using the report that is configured in one of the .mrt files in your website directory in this path:

Website\sitecore modules\Shell\Web Forms for Marketers\Reports

Editing one of the reports by hitting the Design button will open up the Stimulsoft designer that is built in to Sitecore and you can make changes.  You can also download one of the trial clients from the Stimulsoft website and open the .mrt files directly and edit them that way (the interface is WAY nicer than the built in Sitecore one).

A word of caution, however, BACK UP THE FILE FIRST!!!  The Stimulsoft interface is picky and easy to break and it's got a learning curve.  Once you figure out the basics though, removing a field is cake.

Comment: I feel ashamed I didn't actually see that there is a menu for selecting which columns are supposed to be visible. I have found almost everything custom in WFFM to be a big PITA and, for some reason, overlooked at this ribbon menu item. Thanks for the info about .mrt files. Hadn't had to deal with them yet :)